# Glue is not automatically detected when running feature files on Scala

Tags: scala, cucumber

I have a Scala project with a dependency for a plugin I developed which has all the Cucumber steps defined to be used.

However, when I create a feature file with my scenario and try to run my scenario in IntelliJ, the glue is not being automatically detected, even though I have a test runner correctly defined. If I happen to specify the glue manually, everything works as expected but I wanted it to automatically add the glue that is already defined in the test runner.

Any ideas on this?

You have my test runner here:

```
package example

import cucumber.api.CucumberOptions
import cucumber.api.junit.Cucumber
import org.junit.runner.RunWith

@RunWith(classOf[Cucumber])
@CucumberOptions(
  features = Array("src/test/resources"),
  glue = Array("com.company.plugin"),
  plugin = Array("pretty", "html:target/cucumber/html")
)
class TestRunner
```